# Error in installing mecab-python3 on Mac OS

Tags: python, spacy, mecab

My computer is MacOS Mojave 10.14.3.

When I install:

```
pip install mecab-python3
```

And I received the following error message:

```
Collecting mecab-python3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/48/295efe525df40cbc2173748eb869290e81a57e835bc41f6d3834fc5dad5f/mecab-python3-0.996.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mecab-python3
  Building wheel for mecab-python3 (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qj/v415xt754t1cllp2z16ld5yh0000gn/T/pip-install-ncm7s6a0/mecab-python3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/qj/v415xt754t1cllp2z16ld5yh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-_61xc4rh --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running build_ext
  building '_MeCab' extension
  swigging MeCab.i to MeCab_wrap.cpp
  swig -python -shadow -c++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/include -o MeCab_wrap.cpp MeCab.i
  /usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/include/mecab.h:848: Warning 302: Identifier 'set_sentence' redefined by %extend (ignored),
  MeCab.i:89: Warning 302: %extend definition of 'set_sentence'.
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc-8 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/include -I/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/include/python3.6m -c MeCab_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/MeCab_wrap.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  MeCab_wrap.cpp: In function 'void SWIG_Python_FixMethods(PyMethodDef*, swig_const_info*, swig_type_info**, swig_type_info**)':
  MeCab_wrap.cpp:8524:22: warning: 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' output truncated before terminating nul copying 10 bytes from a string of the same length [-Wstringop-truncation]
                 strncpy(buff, "swig_ptr: ", 10);
                 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/MeCab_wrap.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/lib -lmecab -lstdc++ -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/_MeCab.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
  clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
  ld: library not found for -lstdc++
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mecab-python3
  Running setup.py clean for mecab-python3
Failed to build mecab-python3
Installing collected packages: mecab-python3
  Running setup.py install for mecab-python3 ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qj/v415xt754t1cllp2z16ld5yh0000gn/T/pip-install-ncm7s6a0/mecab-python3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/qj/v415xt754t1cllp2z16ld5yh0000gn/T/pip-record-u3x1oulr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_MeCab' extension
    swigging MeCab.i to MeCab_wrap.cpp
    swig -python -shadow -c++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/include -o MeCab_wrap.cpp MeCab.i
    /usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/include/mecab.h:848: Warning 302: Identifier 'set_sentence' redefined by %extend (ignored),
    MeCab.i:89: Warning 302: %extend definition of 'set_sentence'.
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc-8 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/include -I/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/include/python3.6m -c MeCab_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/MeCab_wrap.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    MeCab_wrap.cpp: In function 'void SWIG_Python_FixMethods(PyMethodDef*, swig_const_info*, swig_type_info**, swig_type_info**)':
    MeCab_wrap.cpp:8524:22: warning: 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' output truncated before terminating nul copying 10 bytes from a string of the same length [-Wstringop-truncation]
                   strncpy(buff, "swig_ptr: ", 10);
                   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/MeCab_wrap.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/lib -lmecab -lstdc++ -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/_MeCab.cpython-36m-darwin.so
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/lingvisa/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qj/v415xt754t1cllp2z16ld5yh0000gn/T/pip-install-ncm7s6a0/mecab-python3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/qj/v415xt754t1cllp2z16ld5yh0000gn/T/pip-record-u3x1oulr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/qj/v415xt754t1cllp2z16ld5yh0000gn/T/pip-install-ncm7s6a0/mecab-python3/
```

I installed 'swig' separately, and it works fine:

```
brew install swig
```

What may be the problem? I hope no modification is needed for the setup.py of the original code. Is that because my Mac to new?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't look like this is a newness issue.  I would restart your machine and try again.  Also, I would try to use another import method.

Good Luck!

Comment: Re-start doesn't work. What do you mean by "use another import method"?

Comment: Based on the error message, it's calling the 'g++' compiler, not 'gcc'.